# How to avoid same null check in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have data which is coming from the server. I have a list in which some data can be null or empty. I am filtering the string but I want to avoid same null check. For example

**Movie**

```
data class Movie(val name: String? = null)
```

**Category**

```
data class Category(val movie: Movie? = null)
```

I am filtering the `Movie` and `Category` into `FilterMovie`

```
data class FilterMovie(val name: String)
```

I have function like this

```
private fun filterName(itemList: List<Category>) {
    val newList = itemList
        .asSequence() 
        .mapNotNull { it.movie }
        .filterNot { it.name.isNullOrEmpty() }
        .map { movie ->
            FilterMovie(movie.name.orEmpty()) // want to avoid this orEmpty() check
        }.toList()
}
```

I want to avoid this null check again

```
FilterMovie(movie.name.orEmpty())
```

Is there any way we can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you just have to do it the other way around:

```
itemList
  .map { it.movie?.name.orEmpty() }
  .filterNot { it.isBlank() }
  .map { FilterMovie(it) }
```

Or, if you prefer shorter but harder to read:

```
itemList.mapNotNull { item ->
    item.movie?.name.orEmpty()
      .takeIf { it.isNotBlank() }
      ?.let { FilterMovie(it) } 
}
```

Comment: movie can be null. So how we checking in here?

Comment: @VivekModi See updated answer. Just use null-safe dereferencing: `?.`

Comment: if we use  `.asSequence()` it will work in chain request one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Just check for all three conditions in *mapNotNull:*

```
  val newList = itemList
    .mapNotNull { it.movie?.name?.ifEmpty { null }  }
    .map { FilterMovie(it) }
```

Returns *null* in *mapNotNull* if:

- *it.movie?* is null
- *it.movie!!.name?* is null
- *it.movie!!.name!!* is an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with just the first iterator

```
val newList: List<FilterMovie> = itemList
    .mapNotNull { category ->
    val name = category.movie?.name?.takeUnless { it.isBlank() }
    if (name != null) {
        FilterMovie(name)
    } else null
}
```

Your condition is `if the name inside the movie inside the category is not null or blank, then map to a FilterMovie`.

So you can express that condition in a single iteration and use `mapNotNull` to discard everything that is not in that clause.

In this case after obtaining the `?.name` I'm adding an additional `takeUnless` which will be `null` if the `name` meet the "undesired" condition.

So if the movie inside the category is not null, and then the name inside the movie is not null, and then the name is not blank, then you have a valid text, otherwise you have null.

And use that value to the `mapNotNull` for your `FilterMovie`.